# How can I made zabbix-agent to auto-discover the zabbix-server?

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-agent

I am looking for a setup where I do not have to configure the address of the zabbix server in each zabbix-agent, something similar to DNS auto-discovery used by `salt`.

Is this possible or is missing from zabbix?

Answer (score 1):

How do you install Zabbix? You could use some configuration management tool (Puppet, Chef, etc.) and create a template for the conf file. Then just pass in the Zabbix server.  This gives you a consistent and flexible solution.

Answer (score 1):

zabbix-agent is installed with default config, so you need to edit it first anyway. At that time you can define your Zabbix server. This can be automated using Chef, Puppet, Ansible, Salt.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you need some configuration management tool to modify the zabbix agent's config. However that will not help you much, the fact that you agents see the server doesn't mean that server will start to monitor them, you need to have ActiveServer=Zabbix.server.address enabled and auto-registration type action configured for automating the addition of Active Agents to the monitored hosts list.